# uninitialized constant for HomePresenter

Tags: ruby-on-rails, controller, presenter

I'm trying to implement a HomePresenter to be used inside the home action of my Pages controller:

```
# app/controllers/pages_controller.rb
class PagesController < ApplicationController
   def home
      @presenter = Pages::HomePresenter.new(current_user)
   end
   ...
end

# app/presenters/pages/home_presenter.rb
module Pages
   class HomePresenter
      def initialize(user)
         @user = user
      end
      ...
   end
end
```

My presenter specs pass without errors, but when I run the server and access the home page in Chrome, I get this:

```
uninitialized constant ActionController::Caching::Pages::HomePresenter
```

For two other models in my app, I'm using IndexPresenters that are almost identical to this one with regard to naming convention and directory structure, but neither of them gives this error.

Found a similar, yet unanswered post here:

[Name conflict between controller name and presenter namespace](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6884802/name-conflict-between-controller-name-and-presenter-namespace)

Any ideas?

Comment: Is there any reason you are defining your class under app/presenters/pages/home_presenter.rb ? Which version of rails are you using? Why don't you make use of lib directory?

Comment: this is rails 3.1.1. I guess that directory structure just seemed logical to me. Could you explain why using lib/ would be better?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Figured this out, answered it here:

[Name conflict between controller name and presenter namespace](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6884802/1015700)

Basically, change

```
@presenter = Pages::HomePresenter.new(current_user)
```

to

```
@presenter = ::Pages::HomePresenter.new(current_user)
```

Answer (score 0):

You also may want to set your autoload path to include the `app/presenters` folder. See the documentation for [delegate_presenter](https://github.com/rwilcox/delegate_presenter) on how to do this.

(Also, check out that gem - it may get you where you are going!)